# Condition on abc so that value of determinant is positive

Tags: inequality, determinant

If the value of the determinant $ \begin{vmatrix}
a &  1& 1 \\ 
 1&  b&  1\\
1 &  1&   c 
\end{vmatrix} $ is positive then

(a) abc > 1

(b) abc > -8

(c) abc < -8

(d) abc > -2

MY TRY

$ \begin{vmatrix}
a &  1& 1 \\ 
 1&  b&  1\\
1 &  1&   c 
\end{vmatrix} $ > 0

$\Rightarrow a(bc-1)-1(c-1)+1(1-b) > 0$ 
$\Rightarrow abc-a-b-c+2 >0$

**Now i stuck at this step. Dont know how to solve this inequality in terms of abc??**

Can anyone give me hint.[image]

Comment: Without any additional assumptions of the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, I don't think any of the options give the full condition or correct answer.

Comment: assume that a,b,c belongs to real number

Comment: i am going to post the exact image of question and this question was asked in ISI MSc entrance exam

Answer (score 5):

Take any $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and let  $a=p$, $b=-1$ and $c=-1$. Then determinant is 
$$abc-a-b-c+2=p-p+1+1+2=4>0$$ and the product $abc$ is equal to $p$. Hence, the fact that the determinant is positive does not suffice to conclude anything about the value of $abc$.

Comment: Conversely, no condition on $abc$ is sufficient, since we can take $b=1, c=1$!